# ElasticSearch: Does a query need to specifically use the suffix alias to work against a specific field?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm a bit confused with the use of fields in Elastic Search.

Does a query need to specifically identify the field suffix in order for the keyword/multifield to come into play? Or does the query text automatically get checked against whatever has been setup.  Check the example mapping. Because i feel like the queries i run don't seem to hit the correct field with whatever applied analyzer i might have.

```
GET /Samples/sample/_search
{       
    "query": {
      "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
          { "match": { "Field1": "alpha" }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "size": 300
}
```

or

```
GET /Samples/sample/_search
{       
    "query": {
      "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
          { "match": { "Field1.raw": "alpha" }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "size": 300
}
```

or

```
GET /Samples/sample/_search
{       
    "query": {
      "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
          { "match": { "Field1.edge": "alpha" }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "size": 300
}
```

with the following mapping:

```
                 .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<Sample>(m => m
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(n => n.Field1)
                                .Fields(fs => fs
                                    .Keyword(ss => ss
                                        .Name("raw")
                                    )
                                    .Text(tt => tt
                                      .Name("edge")
                                      .Analyzer("sample_analyzer")
                                    )
                                ) 
                            )
                        )
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

in your examples, you will be executing the query against three different fields

- `Field1`
- `Field1.raw`
- `Field1.edge`

respectively.

Elasticsearch only uses the fields specified (for queries that require a field to be specified). It is very common for a search strategy to combine multiple queries across multi-fields and combine the relevancy scores in some controlled manner (e.g. sum) to produce an overall relevancy score.

With NEST, `.Suffix()` allows you to target multi-fields and still use a lambda expression for strongly typed access up to the name of the multi-field, which won't exist on the POCO to which documents will be deserialized.

Comment: So i think what i am confused about is whether ES will use those 'raw', 'edge' fields automatically for queries without having to specify the suffix? Or must the suffix be specified before they will ever get used.. I ask because in some queries i used.. it seemed like the other fields might be getting used without being directly addressed by suffix and that was the issue.  So you are saying they must be addressed with suffix otherwise they will never get used?